# How would you migrate from PHP to Hack?

Tags: php, hhvm, hacklang

Facebook have introduced a new programming language, which looks mostly like an extension to PHP. They've called it *Hack* and it's running on their HHVM engine.

After seeing their website and reading a bit about it, I wondered how fluid a migration from *PHP* to *Hack* could potentially be.

Let's base this discussion around a web application already deployed to a LEMP or LAMP stack.

Some of my initial thoughts and list of actions include:

- How do I run both PHP and Hack in the process of migrating the code base?
- Migrate from nginx/Apache to HHVM
- Migrate code base iteratively

So, how would you approach this?

Comment: This might be better as several (interesting) questions rather than bundled in one.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw not really. Even as individual questions, they are all either too broad or opinion based.

Comment: @Mike I'll call an audible and say that I said "better", not "perfect" :-)

Comment: I just caught the press release myself and am doing the tutorials and documentation now. I'd assume, like Mike said, that the only answers for now are opinions. Until people start installing and developing on the language, we're all just reading the same documentation and press releases.

Comment: Thanks to @PaulTarjan for adding the `hacklang` tag :-)

Comment: Here is a guide that can help you get started: https://joltup.com/how-to-install-hacklang-on-ubuntu-apache-nginx/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'm an engineer at Facebook who worked on Hack. In particular, I wrote several parts of the conversion tools and then applied them across Facebook's codebase. This indeed should probably be several questions -- it depends on how exactly your project is set up, what PHP feature you're using, and so forth. Some good starting resources include:

- [Get HHVM installed.](http://hacklang.org/manual/en/install.linux.php) Right now, Hack is only available if you use the nightly packages (only available for Debian and Ubuntu) or if you compile from our github source, so make sure you do one or the other.
- [Get your code running on HHVM with nginx and fastcgi.](http://hacklang.org/manual/en/install.fastcgi.php) This should be pretty straightforward -- HHVM is supposed to run PHP code out of the box. If it doesn't, it's a bug.
- [Get the Hack typechecker running on your project.](http://hacklang.org/manual/en/install.hack.bootstrapping.php) This won't do much since all your code is PHP.
- Start [running our conversion tools](http://hacklang.org/manual/en/install.hack.conversion.php) and getting more Hack code in your codebase. We seamlessly interoperate with PHP, so you can do as much or as little of this as you want, as quickly or as slowly as you want. From here, you're golden -- do whatever makes sense for your project!

That's what you need to get started. Specific followups would be best asked as a separate question. I'll try to keep an eye on SO and answer where I can to help folks get started! You can also join us on IRC, #hhvm on Freenode.

Comment: Thank you Josh, appreciate you taking the time to post these steps. This answers what I was thinking about when I heard about Hack. Good job with it!

Comment: Is there (will there be) some formal specification for Hack ? a.k.a. all changes that it introduces compared to PHP. I took a look at your Tutorial, looks awesome, but I don't know how complete it is. Also, you said that you need a HHVM nightly build to run Hack; so does that mean that it will be available in HHVM 3.0 (to be launched next week) ? Either way, +1 for a great answer coming straight from the source :D

Comment: There's no formal specification for Hack right now (but there isn't one for PHP either). Hack will be included in HHVM 3.0 when it launches next week -- we just didn't think it was worth making an out-of-cycle release when the nightlies work well enough for people that want to give Hack a try.

Comment: @JoshWatzman, Is there a way to compile hack scripts to PHP code so that we don't need HHVM on our setup to run it? Is such a tool already currently in development?

Comment: @Pacerier you can try h2tp: http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/install.hack.h2tp.php -- it's still fairly experimental, and designed for a final deploy step as opposed to day-to-day development. I would in fact recommend against using it for day-to-day development -- you really need to be using HHVM plus the Hack typechecker to get the most out of Hack.

Comment: I came up with this simple utility which converts given php class to hack,   http://php2hack.org  I am using it for converting my small projects, will be adding directory support to it soon.

Comment: @JoshWatzman, Would be great if we could have a standalone Hack-to-PHP tool that can be used as part of the development process. In many shops management wouldn't want to install HHVM and with that tool we can still use Hack despite that.

Comment: @JoshWatzman All these links are now broken. Would it be possible to update this answer for 2017 since it is the very first Google result when searching "migrate app from php to hack"?

Comment: @DavidScherer, Facebook killed the transpiler: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/7424#issuecomment-346176489

Comment: @JoshWatzman, Why did they decide to kill the transpiler?

Answer (score 1):

From the sounds of it, it will be nearly seamless to transition.  From the [Wired Article](http://www.wired.com/wiredenterprise/2014/03/facebook-hack/) about it:

> Hack will be particularly attractive, Adermann says, to existing PHP
>   shops. “Ironically,” he says, “its chief advantage is how little it
>   differs from PHP.” Like Facebook, these shops can gradually move their
>   operations from one language to the another.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/7424#issuecomment-346176489